# Akka Http - Getting Multipart Form Data

Tags: scala, multipart, akka-http

I am creating Post Call using Akka-Http where user will fill the form and make a request.

I want to convert this form data to Scala `Map[String, String]`

Can any one tell how to do this.

here is the code Snippet

```
post {
  entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) { body =>
    complete { //How to process Multi Part Form data to Map 
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the `formFieldMap` directive.

```
(post & formFieldMap) { fields =>
    doStuffWith(fields)
    complete(...)
}
```

See the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.6/scala/http/routing-dsl/directives/form-field-directives/formFieldMap.html#formfieldmap) for more info.